# Interactive Checkin Page with Popups

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, popupwindow

So I’m trying to work on a platform for my church. Essentially, when youth come into our new media center, we want:

1. youth to click one of the provided emotions based on how they’re feeling
2. a scripture to popup associated with the emotion they selected

I’m new to coding (have only been doing it for a few weeks outside of work) and I’m stumped as to where I’ve gone wrong.

Originally I was using a hover feature, but now I want to upgrade to a popup as mentioned in bullet 2.

Here’s my codepen: https://codepen.io/mj2913/pen/pXgxOz

```
    <div class="happy-thumb popup" onclick="myFunction()">
        <p>happy
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="happyPopup">I praise you, for I am fearfully and wonderfully made. Wonderful are your works; my soul knows it very well. Psalm 139:14</span>
        </p>
      </div>
```

```
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var popup = document.getElementById("happyPopup");
      popup.classList.toggle("show");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you'd like your pop up to function? Did you take any steps into making it happen or did you just want to know how to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I've added jQuery modal popup. Replace your HTML page with below

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery Modal -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
    <head>
      <h1>Welcome to Friendship Community Church's Youth Media Center</h1>
      <h2>How Are You Feeling Today?</h2>
    </head>

    <div class="col1">
      <button class="happy-thumb popup" onclick="$('#happyPopup').modal();">
        <p>happy
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="happyPopup" rel:"modal:open">I praise you, for I am fearfully and wonderfully made. Wonderful are your works; my soul knows it very well. Psalm 139:14</>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="sad-thumb popup">
        <p>sad
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="sadPopup">Therefore confess your sins to each other and pray for each other so that you may be healed. The prayer of a righteous man is powerful and effective. James 5:16</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="surprised-thumb popup">
        <p>surprised
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="surprisedPopup">Trust in the Lord with all your heart and lean not on your own understanding; in all your ways submit to Him, and He will make your paths straight. Proverbs 3:5-6</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="anxious-thumb popup">
        <p>anxious
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="anxiousPopup">Do not be anxious about anything, but in everything, by prayer and petition, with thanksgiving, present your requests to God. Phillipians 4:6</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <div class="fearful-thumb popup">
        <p>fearful
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="fearfulPopup">Surely God is my salvation; I will trust and not be afraid. The LORD himself is my strength and my defense; he has become my salvation. Isaiah 12:2</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="confident-thumb popup">
        <p>confident
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="confidentPopup">I have told you these things, so that in me you may have peace. In this world you will have trouble. But take heart! I have overcome the world. John 16:33</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="tired-thumb popup">
        <p>tired
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="tiredPopup">Come to me, all you who are weary and burdened, and I will give you rest. Matthew 11:28</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="joyful-thumb popup">
        <p>joyful
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="joyfulPopup">Sing for joy, O heavens, and exult, O earth; break forth, O mountains, into singing! For the Lord has comforted his people and will have compassion on his afflicted. Isaiah 49:13</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
      <div class="discouraged-thumb popup">
        <p>discouraged
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="discouragedPopup">Have I not commanded you? Be strong and courageous. Do not be afraid; do not be discouraged, for the Lord your God will be with you wherever you go. Joshua 1:9</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="pitiful-thumb popup">
        <p>pitiful
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="pitifulPopup">Humble yourselves, therefore, under God’s mighty hand, that He may lift you up in due time. Cast all your anxiety on Him because He cares for you. 1 Peter 5:6-7</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="impatient-thumb popup">
        <p>impatient
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="impatientPopup">Jesus said, I am the way, the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through Me. John 14:6</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="cautious-thumb popup">
        <p>cautious
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="cautiousPopup">'For I know the plans I have for you', declares the LORD, 'plans to prosper you and not to harm you, plans to give you hope and a future'. Jeremiah 29:11</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col4">
      <div class="unloved-thumb popup">
        <p>unloved
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="unlovedPopup">Love is patient, love is kind. It does not envy, it does not boast, it is not proud. 1 Corinthians 13:4</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="hopeless-thumb popup">
        <p>hopeless
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="hopelessPopup">Jesus said to him, 'I am the way, and the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me'. John 14:6</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="confused-thumb popup">
        <p>confused
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="confusedPopup">Be on your guard; stand firm in faith; be courageous; be strong. 1 Corinthians 16:13</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="stressed-thumb popup">
        <p>stressed
          <span class="popup-thumb-span" id="stressedPopup">So do not fear, for I am with you; do not be dismayed, for I am your God. I will strengthen you and help you; I will uphold you with my righteous right hand. Isaiah 41:10</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <p>Code inspired by MIT. All rights reserved to them</p>
```

**Output**
[image]

**jQuery Library - https://jquerymodal.com/**

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd actually forked this to just use modal, but your method is more efficient/helpful.